# Single column to multiple columns with columns as heading and fill with binary values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Given column in the csv file

```
labels    

['N']    

['C']   

['D']   

['A']   

['D','C']   

['H']   

['D','G']

['M']       

['O']
```

I want the labels as separate column headers and fill them with binary values. and there are total 8 labels which is N,D,G,C,A,H,M,O .The code I have written is as shown below contains problem that each label even if it is in this form ['D','G'] is considered as separate column

Code snippet given below:

```
df = (df.pivot(index="ID",columns="labels", values='target')
            .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
            .reset_index())
```

Expected Output:

|N| D| G| C| A| H| M| O|

|1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0| 0|

|0| 0| 1| 0| 0| 0| 0|0|

These output are for the first 2 rows given above
Also add these new columns in the same csv file . Thanks in advance

Comment: So what does that mean, how should `['D','G']   [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` be treated? Should the same value go to D and G individually?

Comment: Yes, D and G should be considered separately and same value goes in both

Comment: in response to your comment: that sounds like a different requirement from "Yes, D and G should be considered separately and same value goes in both" I'm going to remove my answer for now, please amend your question with your EXPECTED output and I'll be happy to revisit this, maybe. Thank you

Comment: are you just looking for dummies? `pd.get_dummies(df['labels'].explode())` ? or `pd.get_dummies(df['labels'].explode()).sum(level=0)`

Comment: No. By exploding using dummies it just explodes columns the way it is in the "labels" columns but I want to separate them and have individual labels as N,D,G,C,A,H,M,O and does not want label as [N,D] or so

Comment: Do I need to reframe the question or explain little more in detail... Kindly comment